# How to remove the track of a N point matlab animation

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, matlab-figure

I have animated the motion of N points in 1D. The problem is that I cannot find a way to get rid of the previous plots and remove the tracks created in the motion.

```
function sol=Draw(N)
    %N is the number of points
    PointsPos=1:N
    for s=1:1000
        for i=1:N
            PointsPos(i)=PointsPos(i)+ rand(1,1)
            %The position of the point is increased.
        end
        for i=1:N
            %loop to draw the points after changing their positions
            hold on
            plot(PointsPos,1,'.')
        end
        pause(0.005) 
        %here I want to delete the plots of the previous frame s
    end     
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general guideline for MATLAB procedural animation is:

> Avoid creating or deleting graphical objects as much as possible in the animation loop.

Therefore, if you invoke `plot` `image` `surf` or `delete` in the animation loop, then most likely you are not doing it optimally.

Here, the best practice is to create the plot BEFORE the animation loop, then use set(plot_handle, 'XData', ...) to update the x coordinates of the plot points.

Also you should add a rand(1, N) to `PointsPos`, as opposed to adding rand(1, 1) N times.

So you code should look somewhat similar to the following:

```
function sol=Draw(N)
    PointsPos=1:N
    h = plot(PointsPos, ones(1, N), '.');
    for s=1:1000
        PointsPos=PointsPos+ rand(1,N)
        set(h, 'XData', PointsPos);

        pause(0.005) 
    end
end
```

Comment: You should put the pause inside the loop, if you want to see this as animation

Comment: @EBH Thank you for pointing that out. I edited directly on OP's code and deleted the wrong 'end'. Now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your goal, then this should do what you want:

```
function sol = Draw(N)
steps = 1000;
% N is the number of points
PointsPos = cumsum([1:N; rand(steps-1,N)],1);
p = scatter(PointsPos(1,:),ones(N,1),[],(1:N).');
colormap lines
for s = 2:steps
    p.XData = PointsPos(s,:);
    drawnow
end
end
```

Note that:

1. There is no need to compute anything inside the loop, use vectorization and [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html?s_tid=doc_ta) to calculate all the positions of the points (i.e. all the `PointsPos` matrix) at once.
2. For plotting unrelated circles, [`scatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html?s_tid=doc_ta) would be a better choice.
3. Instead of using `pause` with some arbitrary time you can use [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html?s_tid=doc_ta) to update your plot.